# Checking my work on a Lennard-Jones potential problem in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Lennard-Jones potential is $$U(r) = \left[ \left( \frac{\rho}{r} \right)^{12} - \left( \frac{\rho}{r} \right)^6 \right]$$.

What is the equilibrium distance?

OK, so I know that the equilibrium distance has to be where the force is zero. So all I need do is take a derivative of $U(r)$. I get:

$$- \frac{dU(r)}{dr} = 12 \rho^{12} r^{-13} - 6 \rho^6 r^{-7} $$

and making that equal to zero we end up with $ r^6 = 2 \rho^6 $

So far so good, that means $r_{min} = \rho 2^{\frac{1}{6}} $

Now to show that it is a simple harmonic oscillator.

$$ -F(r) =- 12 \rho^{12} r^{-13} - 6 \rho^6 r^{-7} = ma = m \ddot r $$

so

$$ \ddot r = -\frac{F(r)}{m} = -12 \frac{\rho^{12}}{r^{13}m} - 6 \frac{ \rho^6} {r^{7}m} $$

When I plug in the value of $r_{min}$ I end up with $ \ddot r (0) = \frac{3}{mr} + \frac{3}{mr} = \frac {6}{mr} $. Which would seem to indicate that the natural frequency is $\sqrt{\frac{6}{mr}}$ which is $\sqrt{\frac{6}{m} \frac{1}{2^{1/6}\rho}}$

Then there is showing it is a harmonic oscillator. I'm told one way is to use a Taylor expansion, so I would have $U(r_{min}) + (r_{min} - r) \frac{dU(r_{min})}{dr} + \frac{1}{2!}(r_{min} - r)^2\frac{d^2U(r_{min})}{dr^2}+...$ but that doesn't seem like it would work.

Comment: Don't they usually write this as $-\dfrac{dU(r)}{dr}$ to eliminate the issue? See, for example, the Argon [*example*](http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/phy516/jan28.pdf).

Comment: Looks like you are correct. That would eliminate the issue with the imaginary quantity. Of course I am still curious if i got the other stuff right.

Comment: I checked your up to $r_{min}$ and it looks okay. Because of the sign issue, I did not go further. Also, did you notice how much cleaner they wrote their answer by bringing out a factor, it looks so much nicer the way they showed it. Maybe if you fix the sign issues, I can have a look at the rest. What does the negative represent physically in this case? It must have some physical meaning. Regards

Comment: Negative forces usually mean attraction (which it does in this case). I fixed the sign issue.

Comment: Your second equation is still wrong (forgot to eliminate a minus sign at the RHS). As for the negative sign, don't forget that force equals *minus* the gradient of the potential as a matter of convention. I don't know the history behind this convention, but it certainly dictates that test particles in the force field move *from higher to lower potentials*. In this way, one can think of the potential as energy, as it appears to be exchanged for kinetic energy. Having chosen the opposite sign here would amount to potential energy increasing by the same amount as the kinetic one.

Comment: So the second equation should be $- \frac{dU(r)}{dr} = 12 \rho^{12} r^{-13} - 6 \rho^6 r^{-7} $, yes?

Comment: Yes. Regarding the harmonic oscillator - which it isn't: it's an oscillator, but not harmonic - you can indeed Taylor-expand locally around the equilibrium. Clearly, your potential is locally quadratic (i.e., at equilibrium, its first derivative vanished identically but the second one does not), so its gradient (=force) is locally linear. Done.